# Less CSS precompute number and append unit

Tags: less

This bit of Less does not compile.

```
h1 small {
 font-size: 100/300 %;
}
```

...but I would like to be able to write something like it and get...

```
h1 small {
 font-size: 0.33333333%;
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Should be `100/300%` or `100 / 300%` (assuming you did not change [`--strict-math`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math)). A unit should be a part of a number, `%` alone is meaningless in CSS hence the error.

Comment: That also works! Thank you, seven-phases-max. Why not write it as an answer?

Comment: That's just too tiny stuff for an answer... (it's more like a typo rather than a syntax mistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:
(100/300)*1%

Less only accepts values and not strings so you cant just add a string after a number but you can multiply with a percentage to archieve the same.

Comment: Ding ding ding! You win! Thank you, seahorsepip. :)